# AttributeError: Parent variable '<Variable: user_id (dtype = numeric)>' is not the index of entity Entity: train Variables:

Tags: python-3.x, entity-relationship, featuretools

I am trying to create an entity relationship based on 2 columns which are same in both dataframes but I am getting the error as stated in the title.

Searched Internet for the issue but could not find anything

```
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="train", 
                              dataframe=df_es_train,
                              index="impression_id",
                              time_index="impression_time",
                              )

es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="viewlogs", 
                              dataframe=df_es_view_logs,
                              index="index",
                              time_index="server_time",
                              )

es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="itemdata", 
                              dataframe=df_es_item_data,
                              index="item_id",
                              )

new_relationship_1 = ft.Relationship(es["itemdata"]["item_id"],
                                   es["viewlogs"]["item_id"])
es = es.add_relationship(new_relationship_1)
new_relationship = ft.Relationship(es["train"]["user_id"],
                                   es["viewlogs"]["user_id"])
es = es.add_relationship(new_relationship)
```

Actual result is the error below whereas this should have worked correctly.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-62d742a93d26> in <module>
 21 es = es.add_relationship(new_relationship_1)
 22 new_relationship = ft.Relationship(es["train"]["user_id"],
---> 23                                    es["viewlogs"]["user_id"])
 24 es = es.add_relationship(new_relationship)

D:\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\featuretools\entityset\relationship.py in __init__(self, parent_variable, child_variable)
 25         if (parent_variable.entity.index is not None and
 26                 parent_variable.id != parent_variable.entity.index):
---> 27             raise AttributeError("Parent variable '%s' is not the index of entity %s" % (parent_variable, parent_variable.entity))
 28 
 29     @classmethod

 AttributeError: Parent variable '<Variable: user_id (dtype = numeric)>' is not the index of entity Entity: train
 Variables:
   impression_id (dtype: index)
   impression_time (dtype: datetime_time_index)
   user_id (dtype: numeric)
   app_code (dtype: numeric)
   os_version (dtype: numeric)
is_4G (dtype: numeric)
```

Shape:
    (Rows: 237609, Columns: 6)

Comment: the error is saying that `user_id` isn't the primary key of the entity. Relationships in FT are one to many, which is why `user_id` must be the primary key

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. I believe it's due because one dataset contains 100 000 rows and the other only 30 000 rows. So there is 70 000 rows of the first dataset where there is not IDs (the featuretools index that you have defined) to match the second dataset.

My guess would be to 'join' the two datasets to reduce their sizes to 30 000 rows. Of course when you have multiple relationships, it would lead to delete of lots of information because you need to reduce the size of all the datasets.

If I found other ways I will post them here.

Alternative way 1 : I had 4 relationships with this issue. I resolved 3 by just inverting the first and last params.

From this

```
r_order_items_sellers = ft.Relationship(es['order_items']['seller_id'], es['sellers']['seller_id'])
```

To this

```
r_order_items_sellers = ft.Relationship(es['sellers']['seller_id'], es['order_items']['seller_id'])
```